# gson find missing primitive fields

Tags: java, json, gson, missing-data, primitive

I am using gson to deserialize different object types and there are some primitive types in these classes. When I deserialize a json object to these types, primitive types get their default values.

So I am using wrapper classes for primitive fields to understand if the field was not present in the json since they are set to null if value is missing.

```
class Class{
  integer int1;
}
```

int1 field gets 0 if it is not present in the json. So I don't have a way to understand if the field was set to 0 or was not present in the json. But I need a way to understand if these fields are present in the json without using a wrapper class.

Thanks

Comment: I need a way to understand if these fields are present in the json even if I define them as primitive fields without wrapper classes.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to `Integer`, `Boolean` etc., what exactly is the problem? If you don't specify the issue, we can't attempt to solve it.

Comment: i don't want to use a wrapper class to understand missing primitive fields

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done after research:

```
public class AnnotatedDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
    List<String> jsonFields = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : je.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
      jsonFields.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    List<String> classFields = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> optionalClassFields = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
      for(Field field : Arrays.asList(Class.forName(type.getTypeName()).getDeclaredFields())){
        if(field.getAnnotation(OptionalField.class) == null)  
          classFields.add(field.getName());
        else
          optionalClassFields.add(field.getName());
      }
    }catch(Exception exception){
    }
    for(String field : classFields) {
      if(!jsonFields.contains(field))
        throw new JsonParseException("Missing field in JSON: {"
                + field + "}"); 
    }
    for(String jsonField : jsonFields)
      if(!classFields.contains(jsonField) && !optionalClassFields.contains(jsonField)){
        throw new JsonParseException("Unknown field in JSON: {"
                + jsonField + "}"); 
      }
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    T target = gson.fromJson(je, type);
    return target;
}
```

Then I assign it to a gsonBuilder like this:

```
public <T> RequiredFieldAwareGsonBuilder withRequiredFieldAwareType(Class<T> classOfT) {
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(classOfT, new AnnotatedDeserializer<T>());
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same, issue.

I think it has something to do with primitive types and default values. I resolved this by defining all fields as stringsm as they will hold `null`s. I wrote a getter that will return a primitive type value but return a default value to avoid the `null`.

For example:

```
class Class{
  String int1;

  public int getint1(){
       return int1==null?-1:Integer.parseInt(int1);
  }
}
```